# JOptionPane not working with ellipse function

Tags: processing

I don't think there is any problem with code, but somehow it is not showing the ellipse before the loop is done.

my code is:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
  background(255);
}

void draw() {
  for (int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "you win!");
    ellipse(150, 150, 150, 150);
    delay(3000);
  }
}
```

thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 1):

You won't see changes to the screen until the `draw()` function completes. Your code loops 5 times with a 3 second delay each time `draw()` runs, so you'll only see the screen update with the ellipse every 15 seconds. `JOptionPane` is not the problem.

You should restructure your code to allow `draw()` to update the screen normally. It's hard to suggest how to do that with your example because I'm not sure what your code is trying to do.